# Difference between visualforce and lightning in salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, lightning

Visualforce and lightning both are frontend technologies can any one tell me what is the difference between visualforce and lightning ....when should we use lightning in salesforce

Comment: You should accept the below answer if you agree that it is answers your question. <-- This is good manners on stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below I've copy/pasted some of the mot relevant questions from this link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ

Note the text below is currently missing some hyperlinks - I will update those later.

**Q:** Will Lightning Components be replacing Visualforce?

**A:** Nope. See the User Interface Development Considerations unit of the Lightning Experience Development module on Trailhead for an in-depth explanation of this issue.

**Q:** Visualforce already has components. How are Lightning Component different and why would I want to use them?

**A:** Visualforce components are page-centric and most of the work is done on the server. Lightning is designed from the component up, rather than having the concept of a page as its fundamental unit. Lightning Components are client-side centric, which makes them more dynamic and mobile friendly.

See the User Interface Development Considerations unit of the Lightning Experience Development module on Trailhead for an in-depth explanation of this issue.

**Q:** Now that Lightning Components are GA, when would it still be appropriate to use Visualforce?

**A:** Visualforce provides the facility for delivering template-driven web pages and email messages. In addition, developers wishing to simply utilize a basic container and maintain more control over the lifecycle of the request may choose Visualforce pages. Finally, organizations that can’t use Apex code can’t use Lightning Components, but they can use Visualforce.

See the User Interface Development Considerations unit of the Lightning Experience Development module on Trailhead for an in-depth explanation of this issue.